# OpenMP, multithreading or multiprocessing (C)?

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, ipc, openmp

I'm having some trouble understanding how OpenMP works. I know that it executes tasks in parallel and that it's a multi-processing tool, but what does it mean?

It uses 'threads' but at the same time it's a multi-processing tool? Aren't the two mutually exclusive, you use one method but not the other? Can you help explain which one it is?

To clarify, I've only worked with multi-threading with POSIX pthreads. And that's totally different from multiprocessing with fork and exec and shared memory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) was developed to allow for an abstraction layer for parallel architectures utlizing *multi-threading* and *shared memory* so you don't have to write often used parallel code from scratch. Note, in general threads still have access to shared memory (the master thread's memory allocated). It takes advantage of multiple processors, but uses threads.

[MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) is its counterpart for *distributed systems*. This might be more of the traditional "multi-processing" version you are thinking of, since all the "ranks" operate independently of eachother without shared memory, and must communicate through concepts such as scatter/map/reduce etc.

Comment: I've always thought that what we really need is something that combines the two. With the two separate, rearranging one's code so as to move a OpenMP thread to a different server in an MPI distributed system is a chore. If there were just one distribution / parallelisation tool such a move could merely be a reconfiguration job.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP is a used for multithreading. I go pretty in depth on how to use OpenMP and the pitfalls:

http://austingwalters.com/the-cache-and-multithreading/

It works *very* similar to the POSIX pthreads, except no fuss. It was developed to be incorporated into code that was already developed and then recompiled with an appropriate compiler (g++, clang/llvm will not work currently). If you clicked on my link above you'll note that a thread enables multiprocessing since it can be executed on *any* of the processors available.

Meaning if you have a single core, threads would could still execute faster since your processor shares time amongst all the programs. If you have multiple processors you and multiple threads the threads can be accessed from different processors simultaneously and therefore execute even faster.

Further OpenMP allows shared (and unshared memory), depending on the implementation and I *believe* you can use OpenMP with POSIX threading as well, though you will not gain any advantages if the pthreads were used correctly.

Below is a link to an excellent guide to OpenMP:

http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/